# Restoring Category Groups and Categories?

Tags: categories

I recently updated a site from EE 2.2 (I think) to 2.7.2.

Somewhere along the way, the categories and groups went missing, but not the category associations for each entry.

(The person who was holding the backup of the DB seems to have misplaced it, otherwise I'd just pull it from there. I'm hoping it will still turn up...)

Is there a way to recreate the category structure based on the information in the entries?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're out of luck Tim. All you have left is numeric category IDs, which at best can tell you which entries were categorized the same - this might give you some clues as to which categories those IDs might have belonged to, but even that's a stretch.

May I suggest you take a look a [Backup Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/backup-pro) after this is resolved?